# DOes creating an index sort the data automatically

Tags: oracle, sorting, indexing

In Oracle, if I create an index on a column, does this mean that data wil be sorted automatically based on that column? Otherwise how can searching the data based on the index be any faster? If it is not sorted, it is random...so using the column as a where clause should not be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an [index organized table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm), the table will be physically sorted based on the index, *but that's not the usual index type*.

When you do a "regular" index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX myIndex ON myTable(myColumn)
```

... it does **not** change the order of the rows in the table. Instead, it creates a separate index object. That index is ordered, and searching is faster because Oracle searches in the index instead of scanning the table, and the index's structure is optimized for finding entries quickly.

Each index entry includes a pointer to the table, so once Oracle finishes the index search it has a list of table row pointers and it uses those to access the table.

The link I gave at the top of this answer also covers "regular" indexes and explains all of this in detail.

Comment: Based on your explanation, how adding a partition when there is already an idex helps? If it does at all? I can ask separately this question if you think it is better

Comment: It helps if the table is seriously huge, or under a few other narrow scenarios. There's more information (actually probably too much information) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm). If you have a specific scenario and are wondering if you should partition, I'd suggest posting the question (with detail) on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), as partitioning starts to get into the "hardcore" DBA stuff.